# Create expression tree to assign to property of list

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

This has been plaguing me for days now....

If I have a list of my own object `SearchResults` and SearchResults contains multiple lists of objects, all of which have a match (bool) property, How can I recreate an expression tree to achieve the following:

```
//searchResults is a List<SearchResults>

searchResults[i].Comments = searchResults[i].Comments.Select(p1 =>
{
    p1.Match = ListOfStringVariable.All(p2 =>
    {
        string value = (string)typeof(CommentData).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(p1);
        return value.Contains(p2);
    });
    return p1;
}).OrderByDescending(x => x.Match);

....

public class SearchResults
{
    public IEnumerable<CommentData> Comments { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AdvisorData> Advisors { get; set; }
}

public class CommentData
{
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public bool Match { get; set; }
}

public class AdvisorData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool Match { get; set; }
}
```

The expression tree is needed as I won't know the property at compile-time that needs to be assigned, whether it is Comments, Advisors, etc (As this is a simplification of a larger problem). The above example is just for Comments, so how could the same code be used to assign to Advisors as well without having a conditional block?

Many thanks

**Update:**

So far using reflection we have the below from StriplingWarrior

```
var searchResult = searchResults[i];
foreach (var srProperty in searchResultsProperties)
{
    var collectionType = srProperty.PropertyType;
    if(!collectionType.IsGenericType || collectionType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(IEnumerable<>))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("All SearchResults properties should be IEnumerable<Something>");
    }
    var itemType = collectionType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var itemProperties = itemType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name != "Match");
    var items = ((IEnumerable<IHaveMatchProperty>) srProperty.GetValue(searchResult))
        // Materialize the enumerable, in case it's backed by something that
        // would re-create objects each time it's iterated over.
        .ToList();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var propertyValues = itemProperties.Select(p => (string)p.GetValue(item));
        item.Match = propertyValues.Any(v => searchTerms.Any(v.Contains));
    }
    var orderedItems = items.OrderBy(i => i.Match);
    srProperty.SetValue(srProperty, orderedItems);
}
```

However `orderedItems` is of type `System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable<IHaveMatchProperty,bool>` and needs to be cast to `IEnumerable<AdvisorData>`. The below throws error:

'System.Linq.Enumerable.CastIterator(System.Collections.IEnumerable)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'

```
var castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(new[] {propertyType});
var result = castMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { orderedItems });
```

where `propertyType` is type `AdvisorData`

Comment: 1. You really shouldn't set properties in a `Select()` lambda. 2. Are you positive you need an expression tree? If you're using LINQ-to-Objects, you should be able to get by with some basic reflection. 3. Rather than putting the `Match` property on the results, you might want to consider using another class like `SearchResults<CommentData>`, which has the `Match` property. If you're positive you want CommentData, etc. to have a Match property, you'll probably make it easier on yourself if you make them implement an interface with that property on it.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior The assignment in the Select is so that I don't have to completely recreate a new list. How could I use reflection to create the above? It seems out of the scope of just reflection alone. Also, I did have a MatchData interface with the Match property as you mentioned, but have removed it for now as it simplifies development for me and is easy to reintroduce. Many thanks

Comment: I know why you chose to put the assignment in there. It's still bad practice. If you're going to treat the Comments as a collection and modify them, use a `for` loop. Anyway, the above code already uses reflection to get the values of properties on CommentData. It shouldn't be too big a stretch to iterate over the values of all the SearchResults too. What part of that do you need help with? (Try to keep your question as specific as possible.)

Comment: The above example is just for the property 'Comments'. I would have to rewrite that entire code to perform exactly the same operation for the enumerable 'Advisors'. I don't want to write anywhere in that lambda ".Comments" or "CommentData" as that is not known at run-time.

Comment: You know how to `GetValue` on a property. I imagine you know how to `SetValue` on a property. Do you know how to `GetProperties` from a type? Do you know how to get the return type from a property? That should be everything that you need.

Comment: I can't see how I could easily use reflection to SetValue, when there are unknown objects and types within unknown objects and types.

Answer (score 1):

First, make your types implement this interface so you don't have to do quite so much reflection:

```
public interface IHaveMatchProperty
{
    bool Match { get; set; }
}
```

Then write code to do something like this. (I'm making a lot of assumptions because your question wasn't super clear on what your intended behavior is.)

```
var searchResult = searchResults[i];
foreach (var srProperty in searchResultsProperties)
{
    var collectionType = srProperty.PropertyType;
    if(!collectionType.IsGenericType || collectionType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(IEnumerable<>))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("All SearchResults properties should be IEnumerable<Something>");
    }
    var itemType = collectionType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var itemProperties = itemType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name != "Match");
    var items = ((IEnumerable<IHaveMatchProperty>) srProperty.GetValue(searchResult))
        // Materialize the enumerable, in case it's backed by something that
        // would re-create objects each time it's iterated over.
        .ToList();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var propertyValues = itemProperties.Select(p => (string)p.GetValue(item));
        item.Match = propertyValues.Any(v => searchTerms.Any(v.Contains));
    }
    var orderedItems = items.OrderBy(i => i.Match);
    srProperty.SetValue(srProperty, orderedItems);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. orderedItems is OrderedEnumerable<IHaveMatchProperty, bool> but needs to be IEnumerable<AdvisorData> (as an example). What is the best way to cast?

Comment: @tic: You'll probably need to use reflection to create a call to `Enumerable.Cast<>()`.